# React both client side and server side rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am working on one react application.
My requirements are :-
1) First two pages should be rendered always from server side.
2) Rest pages should be client side rendered.

For example :-
http://foo.com and http://foo.com/about I want to rendered always from server side.
http://foo.com/FAQ, http://foo.com/contact I want to render from client side.

what is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: What backend you are using?

Comment: I am using express as backend

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ReactDOMServer` and specificly `renderToString()` method.

**ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)**

> Render a React element to its
>   initial HTML. This should only be used on the server. React will
>   return an HTML string. You can use this method to generate HTML on the
>   server and send the markup down on the initial request for faster page
>   loads and to allow search engines to crawl your pages for SEO
>   purposes.
>
> If you call ReactDOM.render() on a node that already has this
>   server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event
>   handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load
>   experience.

Comment: Where I need to define routing ?
If i use above mentioned approach then second page will be client side generated

Comment: You need to define this in a separate file, which will be your expressjs default file i.e. your server. refer to react router docs for more info. The second page and onwards will be client side if you are navigating using Link.